# How to calculate square of a number?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two text boxes. One textbox for input and other for output. when number entered in first textbox by button click then i want to find square of that number in second textbox by clicking Square button. But i am not able to get the desired result. Nothing is displayed in second textbox when Square button is clicked.
Here is Code snippet:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox, new {  @readonly = "readonly" })
<br/>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox1, new {  @readonly = "readonly" })
<input name="button" type="submit" id="btntwo" value="2" />

<input name="button"  type="submit" id="btnthree" value="3" />

<input name="button" type="submit" id="btnfour" value="4" /> 
<input name="button" type="submit" id="btnSqr" value="Sqr" />
```

Here is code snippet for controller:

```
if (button == "Sqr")
{
    model.value1 = model.textBox;
    model.textBox1 = (float.Parse(model.value1) * float.Parse(model.value1)).ToString();
}
```

Note: I have only provided the code which is required to solve the issue.

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading, your second snippet shows you know how to calculate the square of a number. Does setting a breakpoint show the correct value?

Comment: Please fix the title of this question. You obviously do know how to calculate the square of a number, what you're having problems with is displaying a number.

Comment: Did you return model to view again?

Comment: Include `<div>@Model.textBox1</div>` in your view and check if its returning the correct value

Comment: Thanx to everyone. My model was not returting . I have fixed it and get desired result

Answer (score 4):

Here is my assumptions of what you are doing "IF You Use Server Side Solution"

```
public ActionResult FindSquare()
    {
       SquareModel model = new SquareModel(); // model contains textbox, textbox1
        return View(model);
    }
```

And when you submit form on button click

```
public ActionResult FindSquare(SquareModel model, FormCollection collection)
 {
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(collection["button"]) && collection["button"].ToString() == "Sqr")
     {
         double value = Convert.ToDouble(model.textBox);
         var result = value * value;
         model.textBox1 = Convert.ToString(result);
         return View(model);
     }
 }
```

Edit:
Remove removeonly from your view page.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Client Side Script to do it easily

```
$('#btntwo').click(function (e) {
var num = parseInt($('#textBox').val());
$('#textBox1').val(num*num);
 return false;
});
```

> If you want to continue in server side, you have to remove  @readonly =
>   "readonly".

Comment: I know it is bit easier in client side. But i want to do in server side. Because i have done complete work for arithmatic operations. So anyone help me out to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you're having is related to the fact you've got two textboxes (textBox and textBox1), and both are read-only. Nothing can be changed, so perhaps the controller is not firing at all?

I'd also be worried your controller implementation is not wired up properly. You've provided too little code to validate the mainstay failure points for postback processing are not the cause.